# deleted gpt primary partition by mistake

Tags: partitioning, gpt

I have only 1 partition of 500GB on 500GB HDD ext4, I deleted gpt primary partition by mistake. Is there any method to un-delete it. I deleted it using GPated, I thought it is sdc but it was sdb, I realised it after deleting. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After 10min of googling, I found this which helped me

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

you can install is using `$sudo apt-get install testdisk`

It's wizard like easy to use

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: It's great that you managed! But could you still explain a little bit further how exactly you did it, how to use the program, etc? :)